# Change thickness of Navigation Drawer dividers

Tags: android

I have a Navigation Drawer with a divider which is about 2px thick by default.

But I've noticed other apps with dividers that are 1px thick.

How can I change that?

menu_navigations.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <group android:checkableBehavior="single" android:id="@+id/first">
        <item
            android:id="@+id/library"
            android:title="My Library"
            android:icon="@drawable/ic_library2"/>

        <item
            android:id="@+id/discover"
            android:title="Discover"
            android:icon="@drawable/ic_discover"/>
    </group>
    <group android:checkableBehavior="single" android:id="@+id/second">
        <item
            android:id="@+id/recent"
            android:title="Recent"
            android:icon="@drawable/ic_recent"/>

        <item
            android:id="@+id/completed"
            android:title="Completed"
            android:icon="@drawable/ic_completed"/>
    </group>
</menu>
```

Answer (score 0):

Customise Navigation Drawer as you like but use this recommended approach.
In this first child viewgroup is the screen content and other is navigation Drawer content.

Add the View tag and set height 2px,wherever you want to place separator, it will work fine.

```
 <android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/drawerlayout_hirecaptain"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">


    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="#ffffff"
            android:orientation="horizontal">

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/search_bar_my"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="50dp"
                android:layout_weight="3"
                android:background="@drawable/edit_my_way"
                android:drawableLeft="@drawable/search"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:hint="SEARCH LOCATION"
                android:maxLength="10"
                android:maxLines="1"
                android:textColorHint="#000000" />

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/location"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:src="@drawable/marker" />
        </LinearLayout>


        <FrameLayout
            android:id="@+id/frame_layout_container"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="10">

        </FrameLayout>

        <android.support.design.widget.BottomNavigationView
            android:id="@+id/bottom_nav_view"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="2"
            android:background="#ffffff"
            app:menu="@menu/bottom_nav_view"></android.support.design.widget.BottomNavigationView>

    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/drawer_linear"
        android:layout_width="200dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="end"
        android:background="#497899"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:padding="5dp">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:text="LENGTH NEEDED(IN FT.)"
            android:textColor="#ffffff"
            android:textSize="20sp"
            android:textStyle="bold" />

        <Spinner
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:backgroundTint="#ffffff"
            android:entries="@array/filter_name"></Spinner>

        <RadioButton
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="STATIONARY"
            android:textColor="#ffffff"
            android:textSize="20sp" />

        <RadioButton
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="DAVITS"
            android:textColor="#ffffff"
            android:textSize="20sp" />

        <RadioButton
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="JET SKI DOCKS"
            android:textColor="#ffffff"
            android:textSize="20sp" />

        <RadioButton
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="FLOATING DOCKS"
            android:textColor="#ffffff"
            android:textSize="20sp" />

        <RadioButton
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="BOAT LIFTS"
            android:textColor="#ffffff"
            android:textSize="20sp" />


    </LinearLayout>

</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```